# Same Button in different line robotium

Tags: tablet, robotium

I'm writing robotium scripts for my tablet application. In line number 1 and 2 (on clicking line number 1 the next listview will appear with line number 2), there were same button "Go next" with same id. How do i click the "Go next" button in line number 2.

Thanks for the help.,

Dhivya.

Answer (score 0):

Methods which should help you are as follows:

```
getView(int id, int index) // returns View
getView(String id, int index) // returns View
clickOnView(View view)
clickOnText(String text, int match) // match seems to be an index in this case
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   int count = 1;
    ArrayList<Button> bottoni = solo.getCurrentViews(Button.class);
    for (Button button : bottoni) {
                if(button.getId() == solo.getView("com.xxx.yyyyyyyy:id/idButton").getId())
                {

                    if(count==2){
                    solo.clickOnView(button);
                    break;
                    }
                    count++;
                }
            }
```